# Can I use class Equalizer in Android api <9 with the use of the support library?

Tags: android, api, equalizer

I need to show an equalizer in my application, but [`Equalizer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html) need Android 2.3 minimum.

Comment: the whole question is : is the equalizer class included in the support library? Also, the whole source code is available, so you can fetch it and include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use class Equalizer in Android api <9 with the use of the support library?

No, sorry.

That being said, [the source code to it is available](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.java), so you could try refactoring it into your own project and using it. However, since the entire `AudioEffect` framework was not added until API Level 9, I doubt that you will have success.

Comment: Why i am not able to run that API demo of SoundFxDemo from the android 4.1.2 ? That API Demo get Crashed there.

Comment: Please help me for that. And Can i able to play it on API>9 ?